# Java, PreparedStatement, TransactSQL (MS SQL), last insert id

Tags: java, sql-server, lastinsertid

I insert some values into a database using a PreparedStatement, but it seems, that i cannot retrieve the last insert id in that case.

I try to use the same statement as i use for Statements (below) but it doent work. It says, that .executeQuery() cannot take arguments in this case.

In fact, i don't exactly need the last insert id, the number of affected rows will do, but how do i get that? I thought PreparedStatement's .executeUpdate() method would return the number of affected rows, but it apparently it does not.

Here is the method.

```
 public static int getLastInsertId(Statement stmt) throws SQLException {
  String sql = "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS id";

  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
  int id = 0;
  while (rs.next()) {
   id = rs.getInt("id");
  }
  return id;
 }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You **never** close the ResultSet?

Comment: what do you see when you execute this query from console or from any front end ?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I usually do, i promise :)

Comment: The thing is that the query in this PreparedStatement is, sort of, a conditional one (see below), and when i run it in the MS SQL Manager, it doesn't insert anything (as is expected).

Comment: if ((select COUNT(id) as quantity from tNewSchedule where ManID = 464 and (type & 264) > 0 and status = 0) = 0) BEGIN INSERT INTO tnewschedule (type, to_review, manid, parent)
-- VALUES (300, '2010-11-30 16:30:16.036', 464, 271); END

Comment: The idea is that if we do insert something by that query, we execute another one. For that i need either the last insert id, or the number of affected rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PreparedStatement's executeUpdate method DOES indeed return the number of affected rows...

Comment: Apparently, it does. I was a bit put off by the wording in their javadoc, and i kind of confused the parameters for my preparedstatement (they are numerous).
Thank you, and sorry for the my mistake.